# Compile a Python project Windows

Tags: python, windows, compiler-errors, exe, py2exe

I have the following directory structure to my python project:

```
eplusplus/
    |
    |
    ----__main__.py
    ----model/
    ----exception/
    ----controller/
    ----view/
```

The directories: model, exception, controller and view each one has its 
`__init__.py`. When I run the program at my machine I always use this following command: `py -m eplusplus`. But when I tried to use py2exe or pytinstaller the the points to: `permission denied`. For what I found, this is because its a directory I trying to compile, but when I compiled the `__main__.py` it compiled normally, but when I try to execute it says: `Error! No eplusplus module founded!`

I have no setup.py file and I don't know how they worked.

Comment: What about imports in __main__.py?

Comment: Could it simply be that those two utilities don't support having a `__main__.py` and executing directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some very intensive research and error and try I succeeded by doing this:

- I added an empty `__init__.py` at the `eplusplus` folder
- Out of the `eplusplus` folder, I had to write a `compilation.py` file (the file doesn't necessary must have this) to include all libraries I was using (I will post the file at the end of this answer)
- Finally, at the PowerShell, all I have to type was `py compilation.py py2exe`

Thanks for all that tried to help me!

`compilation.py` file:

```
#To compile we need to run: python compilation.py py2exe
from distutils.core import setup
from glob import glob
import os
import py2exe
import pyDOE

VERSION=1.0

includes = [
    "sip",
    "PyQt5",
    "PyQt5.QtCore",
    "PyQt5.QtGui",
    "PyQt5.QtWidgets",
    "scipy.linalg.cython_blas",
    "scipy.linalg.cython_lapack",
    "pyDOE"
]

platforms = ["C:\\Python34\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyQt5\\plugins" +
             "\\platforms\\qwindows.dll"]

dll = ["C:\\windows\\syswow64\\MSVCP100.dll",
       "C:\\windows\\syswow64\\MSVCR100.dll"]

media = ["C:\\Users\\GUSTAVO\\EPlusPlus\\media\\title.png",
         "C:\\Users\\GUSTAVO\\EPlusPlus\\media\\icon.png"]

documents = ["C:\\Users\\GUSTAVO\\EPlusPlus\\docs\\"+
             "documentacaoEPlusPlus.pdf"]

examples = ["C:\\Users\\GUSTAVO\\EPlusPlus\\files\\"+
            "\\examples\\baseline2A.idf",
            "C:\\Users\\GUSTAVO\\EPlusPlus\\files\\"+
            "\\examples\\vectors.csv",
            "C:\\Users\\GUSTAVO\\EPlusPlus\\files\\"+
            "\\examples\\BRA_SC_Florianopolis.838970_INMET.epw"]

datafiles = [("platforms", platforms),
         ("", dll),
         ("media", media),
         ("docs", documents),
         ("Examples", examples)]

imageformats = glob("C:\\Python34\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyQt5\\"+
        "plugins\\imageformats\\*")

datafiles.append(("imageformats", imageformats))

setup(
    name="eplusplus",
    version=VERSION,
    packages=["eplusplus"],
    url="",
    license="",
    windows=[{"script": "eplusplus/__main__.py"}],
    scripts=[],
    data_files = datafiles,
    options={
        "py2exe": {
            "includes": includes,
        }
    }
)
```